# MonoDevelop Using with Team Foundation Server (TFS, SVN?)

Tags: svn, tfs, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin

We use MonoDevelop/MonoTouch to build our enterprise iPhone/iPad apps.

A new client wants to us to use their TFS as a source code repository. Is there a bridge that can allow us to connect to TFS? Perhaps via SVN if we have to?

EDIT: Xamarin's newest version now supports Visual Studio 2012 fully. http://Xamarin.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin now supports full Visual Studio as a plug in.

Answer (score 5):

There is a newer addin available for MonoDevelop that appears to fill this gap.  Link: http://www.teamaddins.com/

Comment: As of this writing, it's still not ready for prime time. I tried it out but in the end I had to just uninstall it and manually undo its changes from the TF command line because it was throwing NullReferenceExceptions.

Comment: @CalvinFisher - Thanks for the info.  Did you have any luck with another solution?

Answer (score 4):

A couple of options for you:

- [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010 (formally Teamprise)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=AF1F5168-C0F7-47C6-BE7A-2A83A6C02E57&displaylang=en)
- [SvnBridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/)

Team Explorer Everywhere has a command line interface, so it won't integrate with MonoDevelop.  SvnBridge could work as MonoDevelop has built in support for SVN, but I don't have personal experience doing it this way.

Answer (score 2):

In a previous project I worked on that needed exactly the same thing what we did was to just run windows in a VM (using Parallels), and keep the MonoTouch solution sourcecode in Windows, and then use Parallels to share that with OSX, where we would develop using MonoDevelop. In Windows, we would simply use Visual Studio to commit the code to TFS.

It's not the greatest solution, but it worked well. A nice side effect of that is that you can always open a few classes in VS+Resharper and clean up the code more easily, and it shows up automatically in MonoDevelop.

Comment: I've been using this solution now for a few months and have been very happy with it. My MonoAndroid in Visual Studio connects nicely too so I have one point of source code truth.

Comment: With that solution running: what is your approach to add files? If you add them in Monodevelop, VS will not know. Or will it?

Comment: It wont, you need to add files manually. But VS will show the files in the directory in light gray, so it's fairly easy to find the files.

Comment: Ah. And what about moving and renaming files in MD? BTW: Just tried opening an MD solution and VS2010 claims it cannot read the CSPROJ files of Monodevelop. It opens the SLN without problems but fails to load all projects, telling my that it is an invalid configuration. I will keep on trying.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a simple job. For the MonoTouch project, I never bothered setting up the project in VS, I just used the TFS client inside VS to commit the files directly. That was a long time ago, though, I haven't done it recently, so I don't remember details..

Answer (score 0):

The least-bad solution I've come up with for Xamarin + TFS is to set up TFS through a Windows machine as normal, mount the TFS workspace as a SMB fileshare on the Mac (Finder/Go/Connect to Server), and manage checkouts manually in Visual Studio while making edits.

It's klugey, but there doesn't seem to be any reliable TFS tooling available for Mac.  And even with the release of Monotouch for Visual Studio, there are still things you have to do through Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Our firm uses TFS and Xamarin Studio and after version 4.1 TeamAddins stopped working, I created a new addin which is an open source and you could give it a try:
https://github.com/Indomitable/monodevelop-tfs-addin

Comment: Hi, i tried your plugin, but i have a lot of error by it :(